# Php add string variable to the begining of file name before upload it

Tags: php, file

Let's say I have a session variable

> $username =  $_SESSION['userUid'];

Can I add it as a string to the filename before upload it?

```
if (!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    $allowed = array("video/mp4", "video/webm", "video/ogg");//Allowed types

    $file_type = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];

    $path = "../videos/";
    $path = $path . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if (!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) { 

        header("location:../add-video.php?lesson=" . $lesson . "&alert=wrongtype");
    }

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        header("location:../add-video.php?lesson=" . $lesson . "&alert=alreadyexist");
    } elseif (in_array($file_type, $allowed) && !file_exists($path)) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path);
        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']) .
            " has been uploaded"; // if checks are successful upload the file
```

So in the videos directory, I will have something like that: uer345video.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before upload no, but when you save it yes:

```
 $path = "../videos/";
 $path .=  $username.basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
```

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't change the filename in the directory. Maybe my question is ambiguous I will edit it.

Comment: it changes the filename after you have moved the file. Are you sure $username exists? you can echo `$path` and `$username` to check

Comment: Yes, it exists. Also when I print the $path I get it with the username added, however, the filename in the directory is without the added string.

Comment: you replaced the exiting two line with what i included right, not just added?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, sorry. I added it after the move_upload_file, that was very dumb of me.